# Apache Mina 2.0.9: Simultaneous transfer is not working

Tags: java, ftp, apache-mina, ftp-server

I am doing FTP transfer from FileZilla but parallel upload is not working.

The server is created using ftplet-api (v1.0.6), ftpserver-core (v1.0.6) and mina-core (v2.0.9). If I upload multiple files, then also, only single file is uploading.

With the same code, if I change mina-core version to 2.0.7 then simultaneous transfer is working perfectly fine.

Has anybody faced such kind of issue? Is there any solution for it?